# Rotate SVG line around center using CSS

Tags: css, svg, css-transforms

I'm trying to animate an SVG to go from being a plus to a minus. When clicked, I rotate the whole SVG and change the color. I also make one of the `line`s from the SVG scale to 0.

You can see it here: http://codepen.io/nonimage/pen/RreKPw

However, as you'll see, the line which scales to 0 also moves off to the upper right corner. I want it scale while staying in the center.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
.add-remove.remove .inner__1 {
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: center center;
}
```

use this:

```
.inner__1 {
   transform-origin: center center;
}
.add-remove.remove .inner__1 {
   transform: scale(0);
}
```